# Right angle with CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have a design that I'm currently slicing that features a lot of right angles (Example: http://grab.by/1jli ). I was wondering if a CSS or Javascript (jQuery) solution exists to pull this off? Otherwise I'm going to have a ton of sprites with these crappy things in them.

Just a heads up, I've already tried "Corners", the jQ plugin, and it doesn't seem to be functioning the way I need it to.

**EDIT:** After doing a bit more digging, turns out jQuery Corners is right for me!

http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/

```
$("#corner").corner("bevel bl 200px");
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Showing the whole design would give us a better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, here is a bigger version of that screenshot. I'm trying to render the bottom triangle in CSS or Javascript. I don't want to cut out images

http://grab.by/1jli

Comment: Couldn't you just have a single right angle image that you reuse? I'm not sure I understand why you would have a "ton of sprites". Could you possibly explain a little more?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit more digging, turns out jQuery Corners is right for me!

http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/

```
$("#corner").corner("bevel bl 200px");
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I've added this to the original question, so you can delete this. :D

Comment: @Crazy: He doesn't need to delete it. It *is* an answer.

Comment: instead of deleting, please mark this answer as 'accepted', so this issue doesn't appear under 'unanswered questions'

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use just one version of that bottom triangle image (a transparent .png, so you don't have to worry about the background)? It could just sit in a div by itself at the bottom of your quote boxes.

Comment: There are different size/colored versions of it throughout the site. There are at least 20 different variants, so it seems inefficient (plus I'm lazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

check these solutions for CSS triangles:

- http://robertdot.org/2009/03/25/triangles-in-css/
- http://www.pagecolumn.com/webparts/css_triangles.htm